# Not getting the correct value from JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting `NaN` and `Infinity` in getting the max value of my JSON Array object.

I am trying to append the properties of a GeoJSOn data from other JSON. 
Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattmorz/skh2L6as/7/) for reference.

The snippet:

```
$.map(data, function (e) {
    var dev_id = e.dev_id;
    var data = e.data;
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        var rainVal = parseFloat(data[j].rain_value);
        arr[j] = parseFloat(rainVal);
    }
    var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr) * 4;
    console.log(dev_id + " " + max)
    for (var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
        jsonObj_device_id = jsonObj.features[k].properties["device_id"];
        if (jsonObj_device_id === dev_id) {
            var nameR = "rain_intensity";
            var rainValue = max;
            jsonObj.features[k].properties[nameR] = rainValue;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cases in your code, where in the AJAX response, you are either not getting the Data i.e. `e.data` or if you get the data you are not getting `rain_value`. If you do not get `e.data` first time, you will get Infinity logged on your console because `var max = Math.max.apply(Math, [])` results in `-Infinity`. If you do not get `rain_value` then `parseFloat` would give you `NaN`.

Validate the API response before such operations. Something like this.

```
    var dev_id = e.dev_id;
    var data = e.data;
    var max = 0, r;
    var arr = [];
    if(data) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            r = data[j].rain_value || 0;
            arr[j] = parseFloat(r);
        }
    }
    if(arr.length) {
        max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr) * 4;
    }

    console.log(dev_id + " " + max);
```

Comment: If that's the case I wanted it to set the `max` value to `0`. Need to set some conditions, but how?

Comment: You should give it a try on your own. Have added some sample code.

Comment: Figures! It's just that, the data that I'm getting is not consistent. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sachinnambiar/0168nzq2/)

```
var rainVal = parseFloat(data[j].rain_value);
if (!rainVal) // check 1
    rainVal = 0;
arr[j] = parseFloat(rainVal);
}
var max = 0;
if (arr) // check 2
{
    maxBeforeTested = Math.max.apply(Math, arr) * 4;
    if (isFinite(maxBeforeTested)) //check 3
        max = maxBeforeTested;
    else 
        console.log("Had an infinite value here.");
}
console.log("Cleaned output: " + dev_id + " " + max)
```

Basically, you needed some checks, I have added comments as "Check".

1. Any number greater than `1.797693134862315E+308` is infinity. Use `isFinite()` to check.
2. `NaN` means not a number value, you can check that using `isNaN()` or simply `if()`